# extracting data from numpy array in python3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, numpy

I imported my `csv` file into a python using `numpy.txt` and the results look like this:

```
>>> print(FH)
array([['Probe_Name', '', 'A2M', ..., 'POS_D', 'POS_E', 'POS_F'],
       ['Accession', '', 'NM_000014.4', ..., 'ERCC_00092.1',
        'ERCC_00035.1', 'ERCC_00034.1'],
       ['Class_Name', '', 'Endogenous', ..., 'Positive', 'Positive',
        'Positive'],
       ...,
       ['CF33294_10', '', '6351', ..., '1187', '226', '84'],
       ['CF33299_11', '', '5239', ..., '932', '138', '64'],
       ['CF33300_12', '', '37372', ..., '981', '202', '58']], dtype=object)
```

every single list is a column and the first item of every column is the header. I want to plot the data in different ways. to do so, I want to make variable for every single column. for example the first column I want to `print(Probe_Name)` as the header and the results will be shown like this:

```
A2M
.
.
.
POS_D
POS_E
POS_F
```

and this is the case for the rest of columns. and then I will plot the variables.
I tried to do that in python3 like this:

```
def items(N_array:) 
    for item in N_array:
        name = item[0]
        content = item[1:]
    return name, content
```

`print(items(FH))`it does not return what I expect. do you know how to fix it?

Comment: The loading question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716585/opening-csv-file-in-a-numpy-txt-in-python3.  One answer suggested `object` dtype for `loadtxt` which explains the array here.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this is with pandas dataframes.  When you read the csv file using a pandas dataframe, you essentially get a collection of 'columns' (called series in pandas).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("your filename.csv")
df 

  Probe_Name  Accession
0        A2m    MD_9999
1      POS_D  NM_0014.4
2      POS_E      99999
```

Now we can deal with each column, which is named automatically by the header column.

```
print(df['Probe_Name'])
0      A2m
1    POS_D
2    POS_E
```

Furthermore, you can you do plotting (assuming you have numeric data in here somewhere).

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html

Comment: Inhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/56716585/opening-csv-file-in-a-numpy-txt-in-python3 he already loaded with pandas, but for some reason wasn't satisfied with that.